# Excel display more sheets in the sheet overview

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, microsoft-excel-365

We are using an Excel file that contains numerous worksheets.

Navigating these sheets has become a tedious task, we are currently sitting at 43 sheets that need to be navigated to relatively frequently. Exporting these sheets into their own Excel file or aggregating them is currently not possible.

We already found a trick to navigate the sheets a bit quicker by right-clicking the bottom left next to the sheet-names to show a full scrollable list of all sheets, but it doesn't really give a good overview.

Is there a way to somehow "stack" the sheet-bar? Like having 3 sheet-bars on top of each other to simply click on? Refer to this brilliantly stitched together example:

[image]

Comment: Apologies for the duplicate, I apparently haven't searched deep enough, thank you for pointing it out!